# How to create products collections in facebook with Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create shop page on facebook with Marketing API. I have succeeded to export products with "[Catalog Products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/products/)" node but I have not found any node for products collections to categorize products.

Facebook allows to create collections manually in Business Tools. When I do it, facebook creates new example of "[Product set](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-set)" node  with name "Store collection [*My collection name*]". Like this:

```
{ 
"id": "123", 
"name": "Store collection My collection", 
"filter": "{\"product_item_id\":{\"is_any\":[1,2,3]}}" 
}
```

But when I create new "Product set" element with API, it does not apper as a collection on my shop page.

What node do I need to create collection of products with API?